# Force compile time evaluation of a C function?

Tags: c, gcc, constants, compiler-optimization

In my microcontroller project I have a function for updating CRC ([`_crc_ibutton_update`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__crc.html#ga37b2f691ebbd917e36e40b096f78d996) from avr-libc).
The protocol I'm implementing calculates a checksum of a packet including its initial sync byte and I'd like to keep the value of the sync byte's CRC as a compile time constant, but I don't like to precalculate it manually.

Is there a way to force the compiler (GCC 4.3.3) to calculate the value during compile time and emmit only a single load constant instruction?

The function in the library contains only inline assembler, so I've tried using a C implementation when the arguments are constants (determined using `__builtin_constant_p()` ). The code just gets compiled normally.
The CRC function is not too complex, contains only one for loop with constant number of iterations, one branch and a few bitwise operations.

Just to be clear, saving those eight assembler instructions is definitely not critical, but finding some sort of solution to this will be a nice christmas gift for my OCD :-)

Comment: Another reason why C++ and embedded programming are more friends than enemies.

Comment: Did you make the C function you wrote for the purpose `static inline`?

Comment: "Force compile time evaluation of a C function?" - This is how I do it: `gcc -O3 -c foo.c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I declare the function behind the hyperlink in your question `static inline`, then `gcc -O3` compiles the call to the function on known arguments to a single instruction:

```
~ $ cat t.c
#include <stdint.h>

static inline uint8_t
 _crc_ibutton_update(uint8_t crc, uint8_t data)
{
  uint8_t i;

  crc = crc ^ data;
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
      if (crc & 0x01)
    crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0x8C;
      else
    crc >>= 1;
    }

  return crc;
}

int x;

int main()
{
  x = _crc_ibutton_update(17, 42);
}
~ $ gcc -O2 -S t.c
~ $ cat t.s
...
    movq    _x@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    movl    $158, (%rax)
    popq    %rbp
    ret
...
```

This is with “gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)”, and it also works with “gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1)” (then requiring `-O3`).

Answer (score -1):

There is a way, but you have to upgrade to C++11!

the new [constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) specifier is exactly what you look at. But for sad, it is [not supported in GCC 4.3](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/cxx0x_status.html).

Comment: He didnt ask for c++